# Matplotlib Axes Labels not Displaying

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

What are some possible reasons that axes labels for a graph won't show up? The graph itself works fine but the labels don't.

```
f= open("test1T.txt")
t1T = f.read()
x= [min_crib_dist("squeamish ossifrage",sub_cipher(t1T,rand_dict())) for i in range(10000)]
plt.xlabel = ('Minimum Hamming Distance')
plt.ylabel = "Number of Simulations"
plt.hist(x, bins=10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`xlabel` and `ylabel` are functions - you can't set the values directly. Your code should read as follows:

```
f= open("test1T.txt")
t1T = f.read()
x= [min_crib_dist("squeamish ossifrage",sub_cipher(t1T,rand_dict())) for i in range(10000)]
plt.xlabel('Minimum Hamming Distance')
plt.ylabel("Number of Simulations")
plt.hist(x, bins=10)
plt.show()
```

See reference [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel).

Comment: My code did not answer with that trick

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearnfrom sklearn.datasets import load_boston
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y = True)
data = load_boston
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.legend()
plt.scatter(X[:,6], y, label='complete data')
plt.xlabel = ('age')
plt.ylabel = ('price')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()

Comment: @AhmadTurani you're still setting the ylabel/xlabel as attributes rather than calling them as functions - remove the `=` sign

Comment: Thanks but thatcdoes not work. I checked without equal sign. I am working on jupyter. I read in some websites pandas has issue with this

Comment: Your code works fine for as of pandas==1.4.0 if I change the plt.label/plt.ylabel lines to `plt.xlabel('age')` and `plt.ylabel('price')`

Comment: @AhmadTurani It's most likely because you already previously set plt.xlabel = 'some string', which redefines the imported function. Simply shutting down and re-starting the program should solve this, but you could also run `from importlib import reload` and `plt=reload(plt)`